# Calling an ADFS service with a .pfx certificate

Tags: php, soap, saml, adfs, pfx

I am trying to connect to an ADFS soap service to receive a STS token. I have been given a .pfx and do not have a username or password. The first service will take the .pfx and give me the token. I will then use the token in subsequent service calls.

I was given the link: somecompany.com/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed and a wsdl. PHP's built in SOAP functionality doesn't seem to support WS-* functionality so I don't believe I can use the wsdl like I would with a normal soap call. SimpleSAMLphp seems geared towards SPs and IdPs rather than consumers. I have seen several other libraries that looks like it would call an ADFS service but they only use usernames and passwords rather than a certificate.

The only way I have found that looks like it could work is writing the envelope and posting that, but that seems tedious when doing several different soap calls.

Are there any good ways / libraries to call the ADFS service as a consumer?

EDIT:

Part of the WSDL:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="CertificateWSTrustBinding_IWSTrustFeb2005Async_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
  <wsp:All>
    <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:TransportToken>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportToken>
        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:Basic256/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
        <sp:Layout>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:Strict/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Layout>
        <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:TransportBinding>
    <sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>
            <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:X509Token>
        <mssp:RsaToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never" wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:mssp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
        <sp:SignedParts>
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
    <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
        <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
        <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:Wss11>
    <sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
        <sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
        <sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:Trust10>
    <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
  </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
 </wsp:Policy>
```

another portion:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding_IWSTrustFeb2005Async_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
  <wsp:All>
    <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:TransportToken>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportToken>
        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:Basic256/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
        <sp:Layout>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:Strict/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Layout>
        <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:TransportBinding>
    <sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:IssuedToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
          <sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
            <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/PublicKey</t:KeyType>
            <t:EncryptWith>http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p</t:EncryptWith>
            <t:SignatureAlgorithm>http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1</t:SignatureAlgorithm>
            <t:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</t:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
            <t:EncryptionAlgorithm>http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</t:EncryptionAlgorithm>
          </sp:RequestSecurityTokenTemplate>
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:RequireInternalReference/>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:IssuedToken>
        <mssp:RsaToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never" wsp:Optional="true" xmlns:mssp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"/>
        <sp:SignedParts>
          <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
    <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
        <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
        <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:Wss11>
    <sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
        <sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
        <sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:Trust10>
    <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
  </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
 </wsp:Policy>
```

Comment: Why don't you post at least a portion of your WSDL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added a portion of the WSDL.